# Generating PDF bookmarks from hidden text in Microsoft Word TC fields

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, bookmarks, adobe-acrobat

I have a long Word document with various sections. The section titles are shown only in the running headers, so in order to include these in the TOC (table of contents) I use a TC field at the start of each section. These TC fields are hidden in the text, but show fine in the TOC.

I then try to generate a PDF using the "Acrobat" menu (Create PDF). To ensure these section titles are included, I defined a style "Hidden section titles" which is applied to the paragraphs containing the TC fields, and in Acrobat "Preferences" I specify that this style should also be included in the bookmarks (as Level 1, with Word's normal Heading 1, Heading 2 etc. put as level 2, 3, etc. beneath it). The style is set to be visible, as otherwise the TC field is not shown in the TOC.

However, when I open the PDF, although the TOC is fine and the bookmarks for Heading 1 etc. are fine, there are no bookmarks for the section titles, i.e. the "Hidden section titles" style does not seem to have been picked up. I assume this is because Acrobat sees no visible text in the paragraphs, and hence omits them. But if there were visible text, it would duplicate the running header and this we don't want.

I know it's possible to have the running header different on the first page of each section (and just have the title shown in the text which would get around the need for TC fields and the other problems), but that would look less neat. I also know it is possible to add bookmarks for each section title manually in Acrobat, and manipulate them so that the Heading 1 etc. bookmarks come inside them, but with a long document that is a lot of work, and it needs to be repeated every time a new draft is created. The only workaround I've thought of is having the text present, but set to 'White on White' etc., but that's a bit of a kludge and wouldn't work with a patterned background.

Any suggestions for how to do this automagically? I'm using Word 2010 (Office Pro Plus) and Adobe Acrobat XI Pro.